# Escape dollar sign in a Windows dockerfile

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile

I want to copy a file to $PSHOME so I have this in my dockerfile:

```
COPY profile.ps1 "\$PSHOME\profile.ps1"
```

Unfortunately this creates a folder in the CWD name "$PSHOME" and copies the file there.

Perhaps this is not possible? $PSHOME is an automatic variable, not an environment variable, so might it only be accessible from a PowerShell session?

Comment: Indeed: `$PSHOME` is a PowerShell-session-internal automatic (regular) variable, not an _environment_ variable defined outside of it. Also, it sounds like `\ ` acts as the _escape_ char. in Dockerfiles by default, so your use of it is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of a Dockerfile, you escape a `$` with a backslash ([see the documentation for more details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement)). For a path separator, you may be able to switch to the forward slash. However, Docker will only expand build arguments and environment variables defined inside the Dockerfile, not values from the external environment or PowerShell. (To understand why, realize that a build runs on the Docker engine, not in the client command line, and the engine can be a remote server.)

One last note, if you want to use backslashes while building Windows containers, it is possible to change the escape character. This is done by setting [a parser directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#escape) at the top of the Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`
```